# Categories and Tags Conflict after Woocommerce Installation

Tags: categories, tags, woocommerce-offtopic, terms

I now have issues with Categories and Tags after I installed WooCommerce. I had a custom Post Type for 'Products' before WooCommerce. After installation, my post type was taken over. All of my products moved into the WooCommerce 'Products' area.

The problem now is that I have two Categories and Tags sections in my admin, which is affecting user searches etc, so I need to keep using my old categories and tags instead.

[image]

Is there a way to hook into WP or Woocommerce to use my Old Tags and Categories globally? Or do I have to go through and change each instance of the code below:

```
// OLD Tags (Keep this)
wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'product-tags', array("fields" => "all"));

// WooCommerce Tags (Empty, Do Not Use These)
get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' );
```

Here is what it looks like now in the when Editing Products:

[image]

Comment: Have you brought this issue up with the [developers form WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce)?

Comment: Not yet, but I will now...

Comment: I got same problem. I had a look on table used by WooCommerce. WC products are saved like posts with post-type 'product', so you can't create same custom post-type (in fact : you can't use same slug as the one used by WC).
Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing the `rewrite` slug from `product-tag` to `product_tag` when registering the taxonomy. It looks like WP does not like the hyphen and prefers the underscore.

```
$args = array(
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'product_tag' ),
    );

register_taxonomy( 'product-tags', 'product', $args );
```